# Plot Excel data From Different Sheets

Tags: plotting, import, excel

I have sheets 100A-100G in Excel with data I want to plot in columns E and H of every sheet. Is there a way I can take the data from each sheet and plot into a separate graph in a simple way through Mathematica?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6):

Create an excel workbook with three sheets:

```
SeedRandom[1]
{data1, data2, data3} = RandomInteger[100, {3, 10, 20}];

Export["data123.xlsx", "Sheets" -> {"data 1" -> data1, "data 2" -> data2, 
   "data 3" -> data3}, "Rules"]
```

[image]

Import columns 5 and 8 from all sheets:

```
importedcolumns58 = Import["data123.xlsx",
   {"Data", All (* sheets *), All (* rows *), (* and columns *) {5, 8}}];
```

Plot the imported data:

```
ListLinePlot[SortBy[First] /@ importedcolumns58, 
 PlotLegends -> {"data1", "data2", "data3"}]
```

[image]